# $f(x)$ is irreducible and primitive over $\Bbb Q$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing

show that $f(x) (\in \Bbb Z[x])$ is irreducible and primitive over $\Bbb Q$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z$.

How pf it?

I tried it.

**MY pf)**

Suppose that $f(x)$ is reducible over $\Bbb Z$.

then, $f(x)=Q(x)L(x)$ for some $Q(x),L(x) \in \Bbb Z[x]$ .

since $f(x)$ is primitive, $c(f(x))=1$.

Let $c(Q(x))= a$, $c(L(x))=b$. ($a,b$ is constant)

then $f(x)=aQ'(x)bL'(x)$. (Note $Q(x)=aQ'(x)$ , L(x)=bL'(x))

=> ${1\over ab}f(x)=Q'(x)L'(x)$.

by gauss theorem,

=> ${1\over ab}=1$ (since the product of primitive polynomial is also primitive)

so, $ab=1$ => $a=b=1$ or $a=b=-1$.

$f(x)=Q(x)L(x)$ is reducible over $\Bbb Z$ and $Q(x),L(x)$ are primitive.

it means that $f(x)$ is also reducible over $\Bbb Q$.

-contradiction-

**is it all right? I know my pf is insufficient....plz edit! thanks :D**

Comment: I feel last conclusion is some....insufficient....

Comment: Isn't this trivial? I mean, after all $\;\Bbb Z\subset \Bbb Q\;$ , so anything reducible over $\;\Bbb Z\;$ will trivially be reducible over $\;\Bbb Q\;$ (up to a constant multiple, of course, since the only units in the integers are $\;\pm1\;$ ). It's *the other* direction (Gauss Lemma) that is interesting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, it must be irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$. Recall the idea of field extensions and this should be immediately clear.

Comment: plus '$f(x)$ is primitive'. if not, don't always.
(ex-$f(x)=2x+4$)
anyway, i thinks this statement is very clear.
but i hope to pf it.....

Comment: I am not competent to speak about primitive polynomials. What I do know is that $2x+4$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, and thus trivially reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(x)$ is not irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$, but $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z[x]$. 
We know that a irreducible polynomial in $\Bbb Z[x]$ is primitive.

Again $\Bbb Z$ is a UFD and $f(x)$ is non-constant primitive polynomial in $\Bbb Z[x]$. Then $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb R[x]$ if $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Q(\Bbb R)[x]$.

So $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$.
A contradiction. So $f(x)$ is not irreducible in $\Bbb Z[x]$.